# Find the tr which my cursor is upon when someone right click and choose context menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code https://codepen.io/anirugu/pen/xjjxvG for implement right click on table tr. It's work fine. The thing I am looking for is,

find out which tr the cursor is upon when someone choose a option.

```
$(function() {

    var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
         $contextMenu.css({
              display: "block",
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY
         });
         return false;
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
         $contextMenu.hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: Read jQuery doc for .on(). It should be `this` in the handler function.

Comment: @Frax Yes, but element that is clicked is anchor which is position upon table, I am looking for get that table tr, Since tr hover class gone when someone click, it doesn't help, (otherwise it can easily done by simply check classes)

Comment: No, but you didn't read the manual. "When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and **for delegated events this is an element matching selector**."

And in "delegated events" section there is an example that is just identical to yours.

Comment: @Frax please check https://codepen.io/anirugu/pen/xjjxvG the event I am adding on contextmenu anchor is not get any information about table tr. yes, I used this keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i I would specify some id to each row using `data` attribute :

```
      <tr data-id="1">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
```

Then when user click on the row just save that id on a variable

```
$(function() {
    var selected_row;
    var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
       selected_row = $(this).data("id");
```

And finally , after giving the anchors  the same class, do something with the id of the row when an option is clicked.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
  <li><a class="selectOption" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="selectOption" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="selectOption" tabindex="-1" href="#">Some More Actions</a>
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a class="selectOption" tabindex="-1" href="#">Final Action</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And

```
  $(".selectOption").click(function(){
    alert("row number "+selected_row+ " clicked")
  })
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/nicosh/pen/errmEm)

Comment: I think I should follow this strategy, when tr is hover store it in a variable and use it when contextmenu event fire, this will work fine since my contextmenu work only on tbody tr.

Comment: @Adrian You shouldn't use hover. It's irrelevant, and will never work on a touchscreen. You have specific `tr` element available in `this` in the function handling "contextmenu" event. Just copypaste the code from this answer. If you need the `<tr>` element instead of row number, simply replace `selected_row = $(this).data("id")` with `selected_row = $(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about the tr on which right click is done by using $(this).context;

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
     $contextMenu.css({
          display: "block",
          left: e.pageX,
          top: e.pageY
     });
  console.log($(this).context);
     return false;

});
```

`
You can also console $(this) to get more information

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like the folowing?
See the working snippet, where I only made a few modifications in the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

  $("body table tbody tr").on("contextmenu", function(e) { // What I changed
    $contextMenu.attr("tr", $(this).find('td').html()); // Added: Save the tr num in the menu
    console.log($contextMenu.attr("tr")); // Display the saved value, just to see if it works
    $contextMenu.css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    }).show(); // Modified
    return false;
  });

  $('html').click(function() {
    $contextMenu.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
#contextMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  /* Added some styling below, and removed the inline one */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #eee;
}

.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

tr:hover {
  background: #c9e8f7;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div>
    <h1>Custom Right-Click Interface Menus</h1>
  </div>


  <table id="mt" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ty</td>
        <td>Stelmach</td>
        <td>@TyStelmach</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Andy</td>
        <td>Hawkins</td>
        <td>@ahawkins</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Lawrence</td>
        <td>Bird</td>
        <td>@LarryBird</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
        <td>Saran</td>
        <td>@SalPal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Heather</td>
        <td>Long</td>
        <td>@HeatherLong</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix" tr="">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Some More Actions</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Final Action</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$(this)** to get the row value. It will return html object(that basically [object HTMLTableRowElement]).

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
    $contextMenu.css({
    display: "block",
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });
    alert($(this)[0])
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a event when someone click the anchor in context menu. please elaborate the answer with this detail.

Comment: **$("#contextMenu li a")** You can use this selector. It totally depends upon what function you want to do. If the function common for all td you could use this method. If you want to change your action, then you have to identify your td with id, class or some data attribute